# Selecting Among Duplicated Rows

Tags: vba, duplicates, field, sequence

I want to select one row of each duplicated SIDs in a field below, which is located within an attribute table of a shape file.

The priority is `R > S = I > 0`.

Therefore, among `SID 87`, `FID1` will be selected.

> (SID 88, STATUS will be S+I)
>
> (SID 89, FID 6 will be chosen)
>
> (SID 90, deleting FID 9 or 10)

```
FID    SID    STATUS 
 1     87       R
 2     87       O
 3     88       I
 4     88       S
 5     89       I
 6     89       R      
 7     89       I
 8     89       S
 9     90       S
10     90       S
```

How do I use VBA code to implement the selection?

Comment: What format is the input data in?  A csv file? Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL in VBA.

Comment: Thanks but I am unfamiliar with SQL in VBA, please give more hints.
Thanks

Comment: You do not say in which Microsoft product you are trying to do this, so it is not possible to be more specific. In Excel, for example, you can use ADO and a connection string to run the query. You should consider Michael Rodrigues' comment.